# linking a host to a network through a wireless connection in mininet

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, mininet

I am new to mininet, and I am trying to link a host to a switch using a wireless connection in mininet/python. Is there any parameters that should be specified besides delay, loss, and bandwidth to distinguish the connection from an Ethernet connection? Thanks

Comment: A switch will need a WAP in order to connect to Wi-Fi. Switches use ethernet, and Wi-Fi is not ethernet. Wi-Fi doesn't have switches. You need a translation bridge, like a WAP, to bridge Wi-Fi and ethernet.

Comment: Thanks Ron. How is it implemented? I can't find it in mininet documentation.

Comment: Apparently, mininet is still lacking wireless support. Seee: https://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/Ideas#link-eg-wire-or-wireless-simulator-support

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested on the Mininet fork called [mininet-wifi](https://github.com/intrig-unicamp/mininet-wifi)

If you check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WH6bSOKC7Lk) there is a video of the integration of the simulator and a real wireless interface.